# How to group objects in an array and sort them depending on an object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

```
 groupSelectedQuestions(selectedQuestions){
     var questions = [
         { q: 'why?', group: 'no-group', date: '1' }, 
         { q: 'what?', group: 'group 1', date: '1' }, 
         { q: 'when?', group: 'group 2', date: '2' }, 
         { q: 'where?', group: 'group 1', date: '2' }, 
         { q: 'which', group: 'group 2', date: '3' }
     ],
     result = questions.reduce(function (r, a) {
         r[a.group] = r[a.group] || [];
         r[a.group].push(a);
         return r;
     }, {});
     /**
     more code here.
     Here I would put if statements that check for all condtions
     I have stated in the question below
     */
 }
```

I am trying to make a function that users call and groups questions in certain groups. Above you can see part of the code I have come up with.

I have a number of conditions on how I want to group the questions.

1. No group can have less than two number of questions.
2. `'no-group'` means the question is not in any group. So `'no-group'` can be just one question or all of them.
3. Groups should be assigned by the earliest date in the questions of that group. For example `'group 1'` earliest(in terms of date) question should be earlier than the earliest question in  '`group 2'` and this should also be readjusted when questions are regrouped or if a question is removed from a group.
4. Grouped questions can be regrouped. And when doing so if any question is left in a group alone it should marked as `'no-group'`.
5. When assigning groups when `'group 1'` is taken assign `'group 2'`, when `'group 2'` is taken assign `'group 3'` and so on.

The way I would do it is use if statements. But since the array of questions can have up to twenty questions and the groups can go from `'group 1'`, `'group 2'`... to `'group 20'`, the number of if statements will become many.

I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e2fyaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to communicate better what I am trying to achieve. Is there a way I can use recursion to achieve what I want to achieve and avoid many if statements?

If there is something that is not clear kindly ask I will be glad to make it clear.

The code in the stackblitz is as follows (it is an Angular stackblitz):

the controller

```
  questions = [
    { _id:1, q: 'why?', group: 'no-group', date: '1', selected:false }, 
    { _id:2, q: 'what?', group: 'group 1', date: '1', selected:false }, 
    { _id:3, q: 'when?', group: 'group 2', date: '2', selected:false }, 
    { _id:4, q: 'where?', group: 'group 1', date: '2', selected:false }, 
    { _id:5, q: 'which?', group: 'group 2', date: '3', selected:false }
  ];

  selectOrUnselectQuestion(question){
    let newQuestions = this.questions.map(newQuestion => {
      if(newQuestion._id === question._id){
        if(!newQuestion.selected){
            newQuestion.selected = true;
          } else {
            newQuestion.selected = false;
          }
        return newQuestion;
        } else {
          return newQuestion;
        }
      })
      this.questions = newQuestions; 
  }

  groupSelectedQuestions(){
    let selectedQuestions = this.questions.filter(q => q.selected);
    let selectedQuestionIds = selectedQuestions.map(selectedQuestion=>{ return selectedQuestion._id; })
    let newQuestions = this.questions.map(question => {
      if(selectedQuestions.length==1 && selectedQuestionIds.includes(question._id)){
        question.group = 'no-group';
        question.selected = false;
        return question
      } else 
      if(selectedQuestions.length>1 && selectedQuestionIds.includes(question._id)){
        question.group = 'group 1';
        question.selected = false;
        return question
      } else {
        return question;
      }
    })
    this.questions = newQuestions;

    // deselect selected questions

  }
```

the view:

```
<div style="text-align:center">Questions</div>

<div style="text-align:center; padding:10px;">

    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" (click)="selectOrUnselectQuestion(question)"
        [ngClass]="{'selected': question.selected}" class="question">
        <span style="padding-right:10px">{{question.q}}</span>
        <span>{{question.group}}</span>
    </div>

    <button (click)="groupSelectedQuestions()" style="margin:10px 0" type="button">
    group selected questions
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: You should use `lodash` [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) function for that

Comment: @NinaScholz What about now? I have logged in to my stackblitz so that the link can work on all devices.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have updated the question

Comment: I think [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e2fyaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) will now work. Kindly try it and let me know if it does.

Comment: now the link works.

Comment: @kmp I have looked at [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) as you have recommended and I was wondering how I could use it to achieve condition number 5. I have just added that condtion. Sorry it was a mistake to leave it out.

Comment: Is the Angular/UI code important to what you're trying to achieve in this question?  That is, could you simplify by showing one or more sample inputs and the outputs you would like to get?  Or does the basic question have to do with the UI displays?

Comment: @ScottSauyet the  Angular/UI code is not really important all I need is the javascript code. It is not about Ui displays. I am trying to create a function that groups an array of objects. That function has some condtions on how it works and will be called by the user. I added the angular UI just to give context. Did I answer your question or do you need any more clarification?

Comment: Well, it would still be useful to have sample inputs and their matching outputs.  I can't even tell if `questions` above is supposed to be input or output to the function you need.  Part of the issue is that one rule is assigning group names, but the records you supply already have them.  Do we eventually ignore the `group` property of your records?

Comment: Maybe the stackblitz in the question did not work as stated in the comments. I have updated it.  Kindly check it out. It shows how the code would work with only one group type: `'group 1'`. I cannot tell what exactly you mean by sample inputs and outputs but I'll try answer the way I understand. If for example you add a sixth question to the question array and group it with the first question, That group should be `group 2` because we used the date of group one to sort the group names before we assigned them, Is that okay or do you need more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that the discussion in the comments did not do much to help me understand.

Here is an attempt that still guesses at some of your requirements:

```js
// utility functions
const groupBy = (prop) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce (
    (a, {[prop]: p, ...rest}) => ({...a, [p]: [...(a[p] || []), rest]}),
    {}
  )

const partition = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (([yes, no], x) => pred (x) ? [[...yes, x], no] : [yes, [...no, x]], [[], []])

// main function
const makeGroups = questions => {
  const {'no-group': groupless, ...rest} = groupBy ('group') (questions)
  const [largeEnough, tooSmall] = partition ((v) => v.length > 1) (Object .values (rest))
  const noGroup = [...groupless, ...tooSmall.flat()].sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)
  return {
    ...Object .fromEntries (
      largeEnough
        .map (group => group.sort ((a, b) => a .date - b .date))
        .sort ((group1, group2) => group1 [0] .date - group2 [0] .date)
        .map ((group, i) => [`group ${i + 1}`, group])
    ),
    'no-group': noGroup
  }
}

// sample data
const questions = [
  {_id: 1, q: 'why?', group: 'no-group', date: '8', selected: false }, 
  {_id: 2, q: 'what?', group: 'A', date: '6', selected: false }, 
  {_id: 3, q: 'when?', group: 'C', date: '7', selected: false }, 
  {_id: 4, q: 'where?', group: 'A', date: '5', selected: false }, 
  {_id: 5, q: 'which?', group: 'B', date: '3', selected: false },
  {_id: 6, q: 'who?', date: '0', selected: false }, // no group supplied so will end up in no-group
  {_id: 7, q: 'why not?', group: 'B', date: '9', selected: false }, 
  {_id: 8, q: 'who, me?', group: 'A', date: '4', selected: false }, 
  {_id: 9, q: 'where is waldo?', group: 'A', date: '1', selected: false }, 
  {_id: 10, q: 'which way is up?', group: 'B', date: '2', selected: false },
  {_id: 11, q: 'when is lunch?', group: 'D', date: '10', selected: false }, 
];
// demo
console .log (makeGroups (questions))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The output will look like this:

```js
{
  'group 1': [
    {_id: 9, q: "where is waldo?", date: "1", selected: false},
    {_id: 8, q: "who, me?", date: "4", selected: false},
    {_id: 4, q: "where?", date: "5", selected: false},
    {_id: 2, q: "what?", date: "6", selected: false}
  ],
  'group 2': [
    {_id: 10, q: "which way is up?", date: "2", selected: false},
    {_id: 5, q: "which?", date: "3", selected: false},
    {_id: 7, q: "why not?", date: "9", selected: false}
  ],
  'no-group': [
    {_id: 6, q: "who?", date: "0", selected: false},
    {_id: 3, q: "when?", date: "7", selected: false},
    {_id: 1, q: "why?", date: "8", selected: false},
    {_id: 11, q: "when is lunch?", date: "10",selected: false}
  ]
}
```

The groups are internally sorted by date, and the groups are sorted between them by the first date in their list.  Any group without at least two entries is folded into `no-group` and the group numbers are assigned sequentially.

The big question is whether this fits your needs.  If not, can you show a sample input and expected output as I have done here?

### Update: inlining helpers

Although I'm a big fan of helper functions and I use that `partition` occasionally and a slightly generalized version of that `groupBy` quite frequently, I'd like to point out that as each is only used once, we could inline them quite simply:

```js
const makeGroups = questions => {
  const {'no-group': groupless, ...rest} = questions .reduce (
    (a, {group = 'no-group', ...rest}) => ({...a, [group]: [...(a[group] || []), rest]}),
    {}
  )
  const [largeEnough, tooSmall] = Object .values (rest) .reduce (
      ([yes, no], x) => x.length > 1 ? [[...yes, x], no] : [yes, [...no, x]], [[], []]
  )
  const noGroup = [...groupless, ...tooSmall.flat()].sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)
  return {
    ...Object .fromEntries (
      largeEnough
        .map (group => group.sort ((a, b) => a .date - b .date))
        .sort ((group1, group2) => group1 [0] .date - group2 [0] .date)
        .map ((group, i) => [`group ${i + 1}`, group])
    ),
    'no-group': noGroup
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. With this I will be able to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: @YulePale: glad to hear it.  Please note in future questions that if you can create at least one input-output pair as I did here, it will make it easier for people to help.